# Current user clear out

Tags: discussion

Recently there has been a series of user removals, and as a result, many are losing rep.

It is normal for the occasional set to be removed but I have seen 10 users removed this month and have lost over 100 rep because of it.

I know from chat I'm not the only one, so I have to beg the question to the mods.

## What is happening?

I'm not asking for names, I just want a reason

Comment: Be prepared to hear "We can't tell you." The [moderator agreement](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) technically only covers PII, but mods are strongly discouraged from publicising information about suspensions/deletions except on a "need to know" basis (e.g. in order to calm down drama in the larger community).

Comment: Although I would hope for something a *little* more informative than just "We can't tell you", e.g. "A user was found sockpuppeting and their sock accounts are being removed". (Which, frankly, it's already pretty clear is what happened, from empirical evidence, so I'm not sure what else you're looking for? I can also say that I recently raised a flag highlighting [a possible case of sockpuppetry](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42459/5373), and both users concerned have since been deleted.)

Comment: @randal'thor yeah I'll add in the question I do t want names, just a reason why they are being deleted

Comment: I'm afraid the answer will be as @randal'thor guessed: "We can't tell you". And what you can know you already know: one or more users have been removed (for disciplinary reasons) or they deleted their accounts.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The mods may not be able to give you a reason either. You could more or less work out names by looking at deleted user IDs and/or suspended users. Remember, these people aren't here to defend themselves if the mods accuse them of something publicly.

Comment: I thought users are banned for sockpuppetry and not deleted...

Comment: @Sid, but the sockpuppets are deleted themselves

Comment: @Sid http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/278659

Answer (score 11):

Along the lines of the comments, I'm probably going to disappoint on specifics.

All I'm really going to say is, these deletions are not in error. I hope we've seen the worst of it, but no guarantees. Apologies to those of you who've lost rep because of this, but it is what it is.

Comment: Are there more users on your radar or is it over?

Comment: @Sid Doubtful. No guarantees about the future.